# how to use moment and date time in D3

Tags: d3.js

when i am trying to display date in specific format using moment and format then it is not displaying . but when i using datetime without moment and format then it is working. can you help me on this issue

```
let parseTime = timeParse("%d-%b-%Y");

x.domain(extent(Mydata, function (d) {
            let data;
            if(d){
                data = parseTime(moment(d.dateTime).format('DD-MMM-YY'));
            }
            return data;
        }));
```

the upper code section is not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

So parseTime converts a string date to a Date object

Your code can simply be

```
x.domain(extent(Mydata, function (d) {
        let data;
        if(d){
            data = moment(d.dateTime).toDate();
        }
        return data;
}));
```